# Prism - Region adapter for content control

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, region

I have Silverlight application using Prism and I am using a ContentControl as a region, something like below:

```
<ContentControl RegionManager.RegionName="Demo"/>
```

In some rare cases the application is throwing an exception

> "This control is being associated with a region, but the control is
>   already bound to something else".

I checked the prism library and it is throwing this error from ContentControlRegionAdapter.Adapt method. In this method it is doing following checking

```
if (regionTarget == null) 
    throw new ArgumentNullException("regionTarget");

bool contentIsSet = regionTarget.Content != null;
if (contentIsSet)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.ContentControlHasContentException);
}
```

In which scenario will contentIsSet be true?

Also is there any issue if I remove that condition and set the view to the content directly?

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario

XAML

```
<ContentControl x:Name="mycontent" RegionManger.RegionName="MycontentRegion"/>
```

Codebehind

```
SomeView view = new SomeView();    
mycontent.Content = view;
```

In the above scenario you will get an error because your contentcontrol is associated with a region but somewhere in the code you set the content of the content control.